# What's the difference between Json.fromJson, as, asOpt and validate?

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

If I have a `JsValue`, which method shall I use to get values from the `JsValue`: `Json.fromJson`, `as`, `asOpt` and `validate`?

Comment: Do you wanna parse the object to a model? You have a raw object? your question is too broad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the level of error handling you want.

What `as`, `asOpt`, and `validate` all have in common is that they will attempt to de-serialize a `JsValue` into the type `T` you specify, using whatever implicit `Reads[T]` can be resolved. Where they differ is how they behave, and what types they return.

Let's say we're working with a class `Foo` where we have an implicit `Reads[Foo]` already defined.

`as[Foo]` will simply try to convert a `JsValue` into a `Foo`, and if it fails, it will throw an exception. This is not a safe thing to do, as the only way to handle the error would be to catch the exception and deal with it, which you might not remember to do. JSON failing to map to a certain type is rarely an exceptional case, either--it happens all the time. `as` should be used rarely, at most.

`asOpt[Foo]` will try to convert a `JsValue` into a `Foo`, and if it fails, it will simply return `None`. If it's successful, it will return the de-serialized value wrapped in `Some`. This is much better than `as`, since you are forced to confront the failure case (unless you do something silly like call `.get`). The downside is, all of the errors are swallowed when converting the failure to `None`, so you have no idea why it failed. If you don't care, using `asOpt` is perfectly fine.

`validate[Foo]` will try to convert a `JsValue` into a `Foo`, and will always return a `JsResult[Foo]`. If the conversion is successful, it will be a `JsSuccess[Foo]` that contains the de-serialized value. If it fails, it will be a `JsError` that contains all of the error information such as what paths are missing and what types do not match what they are expected to be. You can use the `fold` method on `JsResult` to safely handle each case. For example:

```
js.validate[Foo].fold(
  errors => /* Do something with the errors */ ,
  foo => /* Do something with Foo */
)
```

`Json.fromJson` does the exact same thing as `JsValue#validate`. They both call the underlying `Reads` to return a `JsResult`.

Comment: important to mention,`asOpt` can throw `JsResultException`s.