# Play Framework Strange Behavior when Parsing JSON Body

Tags: scala, http, playframework, header

I have a endpoint that takes in a JSON body. I have implicit reads and writes for this JSON format. In the endpoint, I do a validation of the JSON and fold on the result! Here it is:

```
def updatePowerPlant(id: Int) = Action.async(parse.tolerantJson) { request =>
    request.body.validate[PowerPlantConfig].fold(
      errors => {
        Future.successful(
          BadRequest(
            Json.obj("message" -> s"invalid PowerPlantConfig ${errors.mkString(",")}")
          ).enableCors
        )
      },
      success => {
        dbService.insertOrUpdatePowerPlant(success).runAsync.materialize.map {
          case Failure(ex) =>
            InternalServerError(s"Error updating PowerPlant " +
              s"Reason => ${ex.getMessage}").enableCors
          case Success(result) =>
            result match {
              case Left(errorMessage) =>
                BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> s"invalid PowerPlantConfig $errorMessage")).enableCors
              case Right(updatedConfig) =>
                Ok(Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(updatedConfig))).enableCors
            }
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

So as it can be seen that I fold on the error and I return a BadRequest. But when I tried writing a unit test, I do not get the HTTP status as BadRequest as I expect, but the test crashes with an exception as below:

```
JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray())))))
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$$anonfun$2.apply(JsReadable.scala:23)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$$anonfun$2.apply(JsReadable.scala:23)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:73)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:13)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$class.as(JsReadable.scala:21)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsDefined.as(JsLookup.scala:132)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.models.package$$anon$1.reads(package.scala:61)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.validate(JsValue.scala:18)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsObject.validate(JsValue.scala:76)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantController$$anonfun$updatePowerPlant1$1.apply(PowerPlantController.scala:64)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantController$$anonfun$updatePowerPlant1$1.apply(PowerPlantController.scala:63)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:498)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:495)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:458)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantControllerTest$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$11.apply(PowerPlantControllerTest.scala:313)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantControllerTest$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$11.apply(PowerPlantControllerTest.scala:296)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1078)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite$class.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantControllerTest.withFixture(PowerPlantControllerTest.scala:40)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(WordSpecLike.scala:1075)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1088)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1088)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$class.runTest(WordSpecLike.scala:1088)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantControllerTest.runTest(PowerPlantControllerTest.scala:40)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:373)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:410)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$class.runTests(WordSpecLike.scala:1147)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantControllerTest.runTests(PowerPlantControllerTest.scala:40)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1147)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantControllerTest.org$scalatest$WordSpecLike$$super$run(PowerPlantControllerTest.scala:40)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1192)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1192)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$class.run(WordSpecLike.scala:1192)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantControllerTest.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(PowerPlantControllerTest.scala:40)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:213)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
    at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantControllerTest.run(PowerPlantControllerTest.scala:40)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1340)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1334)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1011)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1500)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

Here is my unit test:

```
"not update for an invalid PowerPlantConfig JSON" in {
      // We are updating the PowerPlant with id = 101, Notice that the powerPlantId is invalid
      val jsBody =
        """
          |{
          |   "powerPlantId":"invalidId",
          |   "powerPlantName":"joesan 1",
          |   "minPower":100,
          |   "maxPower":800,
          |   "rampPowerRate":20.0,
          |   "rampRateInSeconds":"2 seconds",
          |   "powerPlantType":"RampUpType"
          |}
        """.stripMargin

      val result: Future[Result] =
        controller.updatePowerPlant(101)
          .apply(
            FakeRequest().withBody(Json.parse(jsBody))
          )
      result.materialize.map {
        case Success(succ) =>
          assert(succ.header.status === BAD_REQUEST)
        case Failure(_) =>
          fail("Unexpected test failure when Updating a PowerPlant! Please Analyze!")
      }
    }
```

Any idea why I'm not getting the expected behavior? I'm expecting that I get a HTTP BadRequest back!

EDIT: To get rid of the unexpected exception, I had to wrap my code into a Try block and I do not want that. So this piece of code gets rid of the error:

```
def updatePowerPlant(id: Int) = Action.async(parse.tolerantJson) { request =>
    scala.util.Try(request.body.validate[PowerPlantConfig]) match {
      case Failure(fail) =>
        Future.successful(InternalServerError(s"Error updating PowerPlant " +
          s"Reason => ${fail.getMessage}").enableCors)
      case Success(succ) =>
        succ.fold(
          errors => {
            Future.successful(
              BadRequest(
                Json.obj("message" -> s"invalid PowerPlantConfig ${errors.mkString(",")}")
              ).enableCors
            )
          },
          success => {
            dbService.insertOrUpdatePowerPlant(success).runAsync.materialize.map {
              case Failure(ex) =>
                InternalServerError(s"Error updating PowerPlant " +
                  s"Reason => ${ex.getMessage}").enableCors
              case Success(result) =>
                result match {
                  case Left(errorMessage) =>
                    BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> s"invalid PowerPlantConfig $errorMessage")).enableCors
                  case Right(updatedConfig) =>
                    Ok(Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(updatedConfig))).enableCors
                }
            }
          }
        )
    }
  }
```

But as it can be seen that there is this additional Try(....) block and I do not want this!

Here is my definition of PowerPlantConfig:

```
sealed trait PowerPlantConfig {
  def id: Int
  def name: String
  def minPower: Double
  def maxPower: Double
  def powerPlantType: PowerPlantType
}
object PowerPlantConfig {

  case class OnOffTypeConfig(
    id: Int,
    name: String,
    minPower: Double,
    maxPower: Double,
    powerPlantType: PowerPlantType
  ) extends PowerPlantConfig

  case class RampUpTypeConfig(
    id: Int,
    name: String,
    minPower: Double,
    maxPower: Double,
    rampPowerRate: Double,
    rampRateInSeconds: FiniteDuration,
    powerPlantType: PowerPlantType
  ) extends PowerPlantConfig

  case class UnknownConfig(
    id: Int = -1,
    name: String,
    minPower: Double,
    maxPower: Double,
    powerPlantType: PowerPlantType
  ) extends PowerPlantConfig

  // represents all the PowerPlant's from the database
  case class PowerPlantsConfig(
    snapshotDateTime: DateTime,
    powerPlantConfigSeq: Seq[PowerPlantConfig]
  )
}
```

Here is my JSON reads and writes:

```
implicit val powerPlantCfgFormat: Format[PowerPlantConfig] = new Format[PowerPlantConfig] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[PowerPlantConfig] = {
      val powerPlantTyp = PowerPlantType.fromString((json \ "powerPlantType").as[String])
      powerPlantTyp match {
        case PowerPlantType.OnOffType =>
         JsSuccess(OnOffTypeConfig(
            id = (json \ "powerPlantId").as[Int],
            name = (json \ "powerPlantName").as[String],
            minPower = (json \ "minPower").as[Double],
            maxPower = (json \ "maxPower").as[Double],
            powerPlantType = powerPlantTyp
          ))
        case PowerPlantType.RampUpType =>
          JsSuccess(RampUpTypeConfig(
            id = (json \ "powerPlantId").as[Int],
            name = (json \ "powerPlantName").as[String],
            minPower = (json \ "minPower").as[Double],
            rampPowerRate = (json \ "rampPowerRate").as[Double],
            rampRateInSeconds = Duration.apply((json \ "rampRateInSeconds").as[String]).asInstanceOf[FiniteDuration],
            maxPower = (json \ "maxPower").as[Double],
            powerPlantType = powerPlantTyp
          ))
        case _ =>
          JsSuccess(UnknownConfig(
            id = (json \ "powerPlantId").as[Int],
            name = (json \ "powerPlantName").as[String],
            minPower = (json \ "minPower").as[Double],
            maxPower = (json \ "maxPower").as[Double],
            powerPlantType = powerPlantTyp
          ))
      }
    }

    def writes(o: PowerPlantConfig): JsValue = {
      if (o.powerPlantType == RampUpType) {
        Json.obj(
          "powerPlantId" -> o.id,
          "powerPlantName" -> o.name,
          "minPower" -> o.minPower,
          "maxPower" -> o.maxPower,
          "rampPowerRate" -> o.asInstanceOf[RampUpTypeConfig].rampPowerRate,
          "rampRateInSeconds" -> o.asInstanceOf[RampUpTypeConfig].rampRateInSeconds.toString(),
          "powerPlantType" -> PowerPlantType.toString(o.powerPlantType)
        )
      }
      else {
        Json.obj(
          "powerPlantId" -> o.id,
          "powerPlantName" -> o.name,
          "minPower" -> o.minPower,
          "maxPower" -> o.maxPower,
          "powerPlantType" -> PowerPlantType.toString(o.powerPlantType)
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there more stack trace you can provide? I'm looking to see which exact method in your action throws the exception but the trace is too short.

Comment: Can you include the definition of PowerPlantConfig?

Comment: I have edited my post with additional information! Can you take a look?

Comment: I just tested my application by running it and calling the http end point through Postman and I still get the exception instead of the HTTP BadRequest that I expect!

Comment: Add, please, definition of Format/Read for PowerPlantConfig

Comment: I have added the JSON reads and writes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your stacktrace (line I marked)

```
JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray())))))
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray())))))
at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$$anonfun$2.apply(JsReadable.scala:23)
at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$$anonfun$2.apply(JsReadable.scala:23)
at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:73)
at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:13)
--> at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable$class.as(JsReadable.scala:21)
at play.api.libs.json.JsDefined.as(JsLookup.scala:132)
at com.inland24.plantsim.models.package$$anon$1.reads(package.scala:61)
at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.validate(JsValue.scala:18)
at play.api.libs.json.JsObject.validate(JsValue.scala:76)
at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantController$$anonfun$updatePowerPlant1$1.apply(PowerPlantController.scala:64)
at com.inland24.plantsim.controllers.PowerPlantController$$anonfun$updatePowerPlant1$1.apply(PowerPlantController.scala:63)
```

you used `as[Int]` in your `Read` format for `id` field for `PowerPlantConfig`. 
When you call `as[Int]`, you are trying to force the given json path to type `Int`. It throws an exception if it cannot (as in your test). You can read on difference betweem `as`, `asOpt` and `validate` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727949/whats-the-difference-between-json-fromjson-as-asopt-and-validate) for example

**Update**

If you look into implementation of `as`, `asOpt` and `validate` you will see that all these three do at first the same thing, but than differs in a way:

`validate` - I do need result either result or info on failure wrapped (just call `reads` of implicit arg on json)

`asOpt` - I need either result or none, if reads under used for resolution return parse error it is ignored as not set at all

`as` - I need either result, or exception. In other words "I'm sure, that this is always such type, if not, than it is general error"

Both `as` and `asOpt` are "extended validate" with interpreting result.

**Example**

Example how to move from `as` to `validate` in hierarchy (two Formats - one as yours with `as` which will throw exception, and another with `validate` which will not throw exception):

```
sealed trait PowerPlantConfig {
  def id: Int
}
case class RampUpTypeConfig(id: Int) extends PowerPlantConfig

implicit val powerPlantCfgFormat: Format[PowerPlantConfig] = new Format[PowerPlantConfig] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[PowerPlantConfig] = {
    JsSuccess(RampUpTypeConfig(
      id = (json \ "powerPlantId").as[Int]
    ))
  }
  def writes(o: PowerPlantConfig): JsValue = {
    Json.obj(
      "powerPlantId" -> o.id)
  }
}
val powerPlantCfgFormatFixed: Format[PowerPlantConfig] = new Format[PowerPlantConfig] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[PowerPlantConfig] = {
    for {
      id <- (json \ "powerPlantId").validate[Int]
    } yield {
      RampUpTypeConfig(
        id = id
      )
    }

  }
  def writes(o: PowerPlantConfig): JsValue = {
    Json.obj(
      "id" -> o.id)
  }
}


Json.parse("""{"powerPlantId":"123"}""").validate[PowerPlantConfig](powerPlantCfgFormatFixed)
```

And output will be not an exception but JsFailure as expected

```
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[PowerPlantConfig] = JsError(List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsnumber,WrappedArray())))))
```

Comment: But isn't the validate supposed to capture these exceptions and wrap them in the errors on which I then fold?

Comment: Your answer unfortunately did not help solve my problem! I understand the differences between the validate asOption and asOpt, but how would this help solve my problem?

Comment: ok, added an example to clarify the way you can fix your `Format`

Comment: Hmm.. but I thought that the validate should do this already and I don't have to call validate on each and every field! Just call the validate on the case class and all the errors are captured!

Comment: If I do a (__ \ "powerPlantId").format[Int], I get the expected behavior! Why is it a problem when I use as[Int] and then wrap the whole thing in a validate when parsing the JSON?

Comment: Have you tried to look at `validate` and `as` implementation I described in my answer? `validate` is not a magic. It just calls `reads` method on Read/Format implicit argument on your JsValue. Nothing else. If your `reads` throws exception (and it is, because of `as[Int]`), `validate` does not care. If you build `Format` using built-in `format`, `validate` is used instead of `as` under the hood, but it you want to build `Format` manually you need to understand what you do and care about errors as well. `validate` is not a silver bullet, it completely relies on Format it got