# Converting from JsResultException to JsError

Tags: scala, playframework

I have Json that may have spaces in it which I'd like to trim. I created this case class to parse with Json.parse(...).as[PersonalInfo] but the issue is that it fails on the first failed read and also doesn't return a JsError. How would I define the JsError case while also preserving the errors for every field that wasn't parsed correctly?

```
case class PersonalInfo(
  email: String,
  password: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
) 
object PersonalInfo {

  implicit val personalInfoReads = new Reads[PersonalInfo] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[PersonalInfo] = {
      val email = (json \ "email").as[String].trim
      val password = (json \ "password").as[String].trim
      val firstName = (json \ "firstName").as[String].trim
      val lastName = (json \ "lastName").as[String].trim
      JsSuccess(PersonalInfo(email, password, firstName, lastName))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855193/play-framework-strange-behavior-when-parsing-json-body/48860843#48860843)

In two words: do not use `as` in `reads`. In case of failed parsing it throws exception. Use `validate`. Example you can find by link above

**Update**

Well, if you want solution..

```
case class PersonalInfo(email: String,
                        password: String,
                        firstName: String,
                        lastName: String)

object PersonalInfo {

  implicit val personalInfoReads = new Reads[PersonalInfo] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[PersonalInfo] = {
      for {
        email <- (json \ "email").validate[String]
        password <- (json \ "password").validate[String]
        firstName <- (json \ "firstName").validate[String]
        lastName <- (json \ "lastName").validate[String]
      } yield PersonalInfo(
        email.trim(),
        password.trim(),
        firstName.trim(),
        lastName.trim()
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That answer doesn't help because I'm trying to transform the Strings (by trimming leading and trailing spaces) before creating the case class. See the `.trim` calls I make

Comment: You probably did not look at link I added, because I do not see any problem to extend solution to your case. Well, updated answer with `validate` only and `trim`

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use the standard format (you can also use read) of [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated)

And then add a function to get it trimmed:

```
case class PersonalInfo(
  email: String,
  password: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
) {

  def trimmed() = PersonalInfo(
    email.trim,
    password.trim,
    firstName.trim,
    lastName.trim
  )
}
object PersonalInfo {
  implicit val customWrites: OFormat[PersonalInfo] = Json.format[PersonalInfo]

}
```

You can use it like that:

```
json.validate[PersonalInfo] match {
      case JsSuccess(info: PersonalInfo, _) =>
        info.trimmed()
      case JsError(errors) =>
        error("Other than RunAdapter: " + errors.toString())
    }
```

The errors is a list of all validation errors.